# How to create AsyncCallback call for Presenter Widget in GWTP?

Tags: gwtp, asynccallback, presenter

Ok, we often see people use AsyncCallback for client to call methods from Server. That's easy, even more easy if we use GWTP platform.

My question is how we create AsyncCallback for a presenter widget in GWTP? Thre is no server involved.

Ex, i want to create a ConfirmationPresenter which has 2 buttons (ok & cancel). When user click ok the system will go to onSuccess of AsyncCallback method.

```
     private AsyncCallback<ConfirmResult> confirmCallback=new AsyncCallback<ConfirmResult>(){

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
         @Override
          public void onSuccess(ConfirmResult result) {
               //do something here
          }
       };
```

to call the above method we can do this:

```
     Confirmation action=new Confirmation();
     String msg="pls click ok to confirm");
     action.set(msg);
     dispatchAsync.execute(action, confirmCallback);
```

I just know the basic structure of Async Callback but I don't know how to create it. I can only create it if i use eClipse, but it will create for server call.

If you can provide a very simple example based on GWTP platform then it will be great. Some other examples on internet was not based on GWTP platform & too complicated.

Comment: Do you want a action call on the presenter widgets????

Comment: Do you want an action call on the presenter widgets? -- user2689075

Comment: i want to call a Presenter Widget like to call an action. The reason is that Jscript is single thread, so it won't stop when u open a new Widget, but continue to run to the next line of code,